# Tengo un problema con strings en C

Tags: c, string

Estoy aprendiendo a manipular strings en C, me dieron a realizar el siguiente ejercicio:

**1) El usuario ingresará su nombre y el programa lo mostrará en orden inverso.
Pepe -> epeP**

El problema que tengo es que, si bien mi código realiza lo pedido, al mostrarlo en pantalla me aparece un caracter que no se de donde sale bien, dejo el codigo de ejemplo para ser mas claro...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define L 15

int main(){
    char NOMBRE[L];
    int I;
    printf("Ingresa tu nombre... \n");

    gets(NOMBRE);
    
    for(I=L-1;I>=0;I--)
      printf("%c",NOMBRE[I]);
}
```

El resultado en pantalla es el siguiente:

**Ingresa tu nombre...**

**Pepe**

**►     ú epeP**

Mi duda es porque me salen esos caracteres sin sentido...
Espero haber sido claro, aguardo por vuestra ayuda.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [c](/questions/tagged/c), lo que se conoce como "*strings*" son en realidad formaciones<sup>1</sup> de elementos de tipo `char`, como puede verse en tu primera línea de `main`:

```
// 'nombre'  es una formación de L (15) elementos de tipo 'char'.
char nombre[L];
```

En memoria tiene un aspecto como este:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Pero en C (y otros lenguajes) las formaciones tienen la particularidad de que si no les das ningún valor a sus elementos, éstos tendrán un valor indeterminado al momento de crearse, por lo que tu formación `nombre` en realidad tiene un aspecto como este em memoria:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? |

Cuando lees sobre `nombre` lo escrito por la consola, la memoria queda de esta manera:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `'P'` | `'e'` | `'p'` | `'e'` | `0` | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? |

El cero (`0`) es la marca de final de cadena (final de "*string*"). Cuando haces el bucle de impresión, dado que imprimes desde el final, escribirás el contenido de esa memoria a la que no se le dio valor, de ahí que te aparezcan "*caracteres sin sentido*". Tienes estas opciones para solucionarlo:

1. Inicializa la formación: Si pones todos los elementos de `nombre` a cero, en el momento de imprimirlos no se mostrará nada, puedes hacerlo inicializando así:

   ```
   char nombre[L] = ""; // Todos los elementos quedan a cero.
   ```
2. Imprime sólo la parte de la formación que tiene valores.

   ```
   char NOMBRE[L];
   printf("Ingresa tu nombre... \n");

   gets(NOMBRE);
   int longitud = strlen(NOMBRE);

   for (int indice = longitud - 1; indice >= 0; --indice)
       printf("%c", NOMBRE[indice]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

En ningún momento inicializas `NOMBRE`. Por lo tanto puede tener basura.

Si [pruebas el siguiente código](https://tio.run/##vZDBCsIwEETv@YolIiRUiwa8WPUuFH/A9tCmaQ3oRtJ4Er@9xlZFigcPxUBY2B1mhienlZRNM9Ioj5dCwap2hTbhYUNGhSo1KohhviBEo4NTppHxKwH/5CGzgOaUW7WP04i0y7P1spLRXbsHadBphWoJlEetoDSWPZw0rGEW@bGC2I8g4O3502Ms6eQVoFPeS0hwi5VVdQbu8lSFYZggfQkr5WrWHfjf2n1AEZ6Kt6E06vVOsMsXgxUQv/ERb0A9PuI7oMEL3pomyyV5/Ds) verás que antes de leer el nombre desde el terminal, este tiene basura. Después también la conserva.

En cambio, `nombre2` que sí es inicializado solo contiene caracteres nulos (0). Luego de leer desde el terminal se muestra bien.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define L 15

int main(){
    char nombre[L];

    printf("Nombre contiene: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        printf("%c", nombre[i]);

    printf("\nIngresa tu nombre...\n");

    gets(nombre);

    printf("Nombre contiene: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        printf("%c", nombre[i]);

    char nombre2[L] = "";
    printf("\n\nNombre2 contiene: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        printf("%c", nombre2[i]);

    printf("\nIngresa tu nombre2...\n");
    gets(nombre2);

    printf("Nombre2 contiene: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        printf("%c", nombre2[i]);
}
```

Como pudiste ver en el ejemplo, puedes inicializar un arreglo de caracteres es asignándole un literal de cadena de texto. De preferencia una cadena vacía si no necesitas que tenga un texto en específico.

Alternativamente, puedes establecer cada elemento en un carácter nulo. Así:

```
for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    nombre[i] = 0;
```