# Fallo al sumar totales en cuadro de matrices en c++

Tags: c++, c++11

[image: MATRIZ con fallo al sumar totales]

Mi codigo tiene un problema y no logro dar con el, quiero imprimir los totales por facultad y por materia y a pesar de que uno de ellos sí está sumando bien, el resto no. He tanteado mucho intentando localizar donde está el error, pero como dije, no doy con el.

Dejo todo el código a continuación para que vean qué podría ser.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    //Declaración de variables
    string facultades[3]={"Civil     ","Industrial","Sistemas  "};
    string materias[2]={"Espanol","Matematicas"};
    int f[2]; int a[3]; int matriz[3][3];
    int auxfac=0, auxmat=0;
    string facmayor, matyor; 

    //Encabezado y lectura de la cantidad de estudiantes.
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout<<"\n          Informe de facultad"<<endl;
    cout<<"          "<<facultades[i]<<endl;
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        
    cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de estudiantes de "<<materias[j]<<" ";       //Lectura del numero de estudiantes
    cin>>matriz[i][j]; 
        }
    }
    
     //Acumuladores para obtener a[3] = total por facultad
     //                          f[2] = total por materias
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            a[i] += matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            f[j] += matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    //Facultad con mayor matrícula
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if (auxfac<a[i]){
            facmayor=facultades[i];
        }
    }

    //Materias con mayor matricula
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        if (auxmat<f[i]){
            matyor=materias[i];
        }
    }
    
    
    // impresión del encabezado 
        cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"             espanol  matematicas  totales por "<<endl;
    cout<<"                          facultad"<<endl;
    
    //Impresión de la matriz y el total por facultad
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout<<facultades[i]<<" ";
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            cout<<"      "<<matriz[i][j]; //Matriz
            }
            cout<<"               "<<a[i]; //total por facultad
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    
    //Impresión de los totales por materias.
    cout<<"\nTotales  "<<endl;
    cout<<"Por materias";
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){    
    cout<<"   "<<f[i];
    }       
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\nLa facultad con mayor cantidad de matriculas es: "<<facmayor<<endl;
    cout<<"\nLas materias con mayor cantidad de matriculas es: "<<matyor<<endl;
    
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes inicializar tus variables. Especialmente cuando el resultado depende del valor previo. De lo contrario contienen basura. Por ejemplo:

```
// Inicializado
int n = 0;
n += 10; // 10 + 0

// Sin inicializar
int n;
n += 10; // 10 + ?
```

Si solo vas a asignar la variable, no hay ningún problema.

```
// Inicializado
int a = 0;

// Sin inicializar
int a;
a = 0; // También inicializa la variable
```

El caso es que en ningún momento inicializas los arreglos `a` y `f`.

Puedes hacerlo indicandole cuáles quieres que sean cada uno de sus elementos:

```
int a[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
```

O solo indicar el primero y el resto de establecerá en 0:

```
int a[3] = { 0 };
```

Una tercera opción es recorrer el arreglo asignándole valores. Por ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    a[i] = 0;
}
```

- Más información sobre inicialización: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization
- Una pregunta similar a la tuya:
  [Tengo un problema con strings en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/541577/169744)